# How can I make like the image below?

Tags: extjs, extjs6

```
 var cond = new Ext.panel.Panel({  
                                xtype : 'toolbar', 
                                dock : 'top', 
                                region : 'north' , 
                                layout : { 
                                           type : 'table' ,
                                           columns : '3' 
                                          } ,
                                items [ 
                                           { xtype : 'textfield' } , 
                                           { xtype : 'textfield'} 
                                      ]
});

[~~~~~cell~~~~][~~cell~~~][~cell~~~]
[~~~~cell~~~~][~~~~cell~][~~~~cell~]
[ cell ][cell][~~~~~~~~cell~~~~~~~~]
```

here image show i want table cell width difference.( i want to not same ).

How can I make like the image below ?

top source is base...

i want table cell width difference( not same )!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read here to have more informations http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Table 
same on ext 6.

you can't use only tree columns to have this configuration.
table layout uses colspan and row span to set element dimensions.

so for example

```
1 2 3
[][][] -> every element colspan 1
[  ][] -> first element colspan 2 and second colspan 1
```

so if you have different dimensions like yours you must have more columns to set perfectly dimensions